# Scale OpenAPI with common dependencies between services

Tags: api, code-generation, openapi, openapi-generator

Assume that there are two or more services with common models in their API specification and we use api first approach with OpenAPI.

To illustrate:

- serviceA in its API definition has CommonModel
- serviceB in its API definition has CommonModel

Where to define CommonModel?

1. in some distinct module and then ref it from all services using it
2. in one of the services and then ref it from all services using it
3. define it in each service and then resolve it during model
   generation phase to avoid duplication conflicts
4. ...

By service I mean different applications, api of each service auto-generated from OpenAPI spec

What is the best practices to scale and handle common model hell with OpenAPI approach?

Answer (score 0):

In swagger hub there is feature called [domains](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/domains/index?_ga=2.263387020.1433421912.1581344490-569212989.1581071516) which is intended to reuse common models, params, etc. Idea to have commons in one place